# Unity animation freeze when played first time

Tags: android, animation, unity-game-engine

My animation freezes when I press the button for the first time. It happens only on android devices and if I press the button for the next times, everything work perfectly. I use animator component. If I restart the game, animation will will freeze again when i press any button. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should post the relevant code. Almost no way we can help you otherwise.

Comment: Please show more detail. Like code, your component' screenshot, or a video recording.

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, your problem is that your game is loading the animation at the first time you fire it. Maybe because the gameobject or the or the animator was inactive till that moment, hard to say. If that is the case, you will probably fix it by preloading the animation somehow.

Another possible situation, is that when you play your animation you also instantiate some prefab. In that case, you would also make the game suffer in order to create the instances. To solve that, you could use a pool and instantiate the prefabs earlier in the game.